# Desktop Management for Windows 7?

Tags: windows

I went through this thread and most of the replies seem to be around 9 years old:

https://superuser.com/questions/14835/organize-desktop-icons-on-windows-into-categories-or-sections

Out of the replies in the above thread, I liked Fences the best, but it doesn't seem to be free.

Anything free that is decent? I'm using Windows 7. Thank you.

EDIT:

I was looking at Nimi Places, but according to reviews, the EULA states all types of data collections.

https://alternativeto.net/software/nimi-places/reviews/

Comment: A quick google found [this page](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-desktop-management/), and there were other results from https://www.google.com/search?q=desktop+organizer+windows+free - I don't use this sort of software, so I can't comment on how good any of them are. I _can_ say that Google, used properly, is your friend.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Yeah, I was going through some of the sites, I was afraid to whitelist the first one. I was wondering if there were any others. Thank you.

Comment: You can try one of these programs shown at this page https://www.online-tech-tips.com/software-reviews/7-best-windows-alternative-shell-replacement-programs/